# Swift ViewController doesn't refresh background color

Tags: ios, swift, themes, refresh, viewcontroller

I have a MainView Controller and a second SettingsView Controller.
In SettingsView controller, I let user select a background color, save it and move back to MainView Controller.
I use Navigation controller segue to move from Main to Settings and use dismissViewControllerAnimated to move back to Main.

My problem is when I set background for main view, it doesn't show up.
But if I close and restart app then it comes up correctly.
Is it because Main view is already open and not refreshed back?

Here is the code:

Settings:

```
let defaults = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()
    defaults.setObject("theme", forKey: "BackgroundColor")
```

Main:

```
 override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        view.backgroundColor = UIColor.clearColor()
        var backgroundLayer = Util.GetTheme()
        backgroundLayer.frame = view.frame
        view.layer.insertSublayer(backgroundLayer, atIndex: 0)
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

As per your requirement, you need to move the code for changing color to `viewWillAppear` method. Since viewDidLoad will be called only once at the time when it get loaded to memory. `viewWillAppear` will be called each time it will come to foreground or visible to user.

But where you are saving selected color and applying the saved color?

Answer (score 0):

Try This code :

```
class Colors {
let colorTop = UIColor(red: 192.0/255.0, green: 38.0/255.0, blue: 42.0/255.0, alpha: 1.0).CGColor
let colorBottom = UIColor(red: 35.0/255.0, green: 2.0/255.0, blue: 2.0/255.0, alpha: 1.0).CGColor

let gl: CAGradientLayer

init() {
    gl = CAGradientLayer()
    gl.colors = [ colorTop, colorBottom]
    gl.locations = [ 0.0, 1.0]
}
}
```